# Is sending the complains to the whole community instead of the Title IX office legal?

Tags: united-states, education, harassment, sex-discrimination

A woman received an unwanted "offensive" text message during an official college event from a man: "I am not sure if you are dressing like in a night-club". Although the text message seemed to be polite and did not involve protected characteristics, the woman felt offended, emotionally harmed and believed that the man is sexually harassing her.

Since it happened only once, the woman thinks that the title IX allegation would have a slim chance to be successful (i.e. legally not harassing); and during the conversation, the woman responded with sexually offensive language, so the woman did not bother to bring the entire thing up to file a formal Title IX complain.

Instead, the woman choose to distribute her version of the story among the community and write complains to the professors also in the event, referring the man as a "harasser". The man's daily research and study was severely harmed because many are no longer willing to work with him. Getting her messages, some others also write to the man harshly accusing him for the "misconduct".

What legal troubles will the woman (and others who accused the man) be facing? Maybe Title IX allegation?

Comment: Woman gets slightly offensive text, responds possibly more sexually, then woman decides to destroy the man's career... Am I missing something?

Comment: @RonBeyer This is what actually happened. I was not the victim but I was in that community. It makes me feel bad. It seems to me that the man don't have many resources against the woman: he's chance of winning a title IX seems to be also slim and a law sue is too costly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Nij Hi Nij, I appreciate you for bringing that up. The other post is about summary statistics but this post is more about specific legal actions and consequences.

Comment: @RonBeyer Wait, do you believe that the man's text can be legally classified as "offensive" or involves "protected characteristics"?

Comment: No, my point is that this woman took it upon herself to destroy somebody over something that could have been handled differently. I may be missing details, but it seems like although the man behaved reprehensibly in the text, the resolution by the woman seems to be several orders of magnitude more reprehensible, destroying the man's career/social standing over a text. Not really the place for that type of soapbox, if you want to have that discussion, try [Interpersonal Skills.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

If the factual information contained in her statement (without regard to the spin or interpretation she places on those facts, which are a matter of opinion) are true, she has every legal right and privilege to continue what she is doing.

If the factual information is false in some material respect that damages his reputation, it would be possible for the person who is the subject of the statements to bring a defamation against her seeking money damages, although it is unlikely to prevail and likely to give rise to only a nominal money damages award if he prevails.

Comment: Note that the university might have a code of conduct that was breached. That might bring the professor some recourse.